# Overpass query grouping results by tag value

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'd like to ask overpass turbo how many objects have the same property in a given area. 
For instance, `what is the distribution of the building tag?` could return:

`// for a total of 3005 buildings for instance
yes: 3000
church: 3
school: 2`

It would help me find where buildings have not been updated for a while, based on the `source` tag attribute.

Comment: This information is already contained in the Overpass API results. You just need to parse the file to obtain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @scai, I wrote a shell script doing the job:

```
wget -O "/tmp/file" "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:csv('source', 'building';false)][timeout:25];
    area[boundary='administrative'][admin_level='8']['name'='SomeCity']->.searchArea;
    (
      node['building'][source](area.searchArea);
      way['building'][source](area.searchArea);
      relation['building'][source](area.searchArea);
    );
    out;"
sort "/tmp/file" | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: `out:csv` provides a setting to suppress the header line, i.e. by saying `[out:csv('source', 'building';false]`. This way you could get rid of the `tail -n +1` in your script.